# (Num a) vs (Eq a)

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

As an exercise for college, I was asked to create a program to test if a matrix is higher triangular.
The type of the function was predefined in the question. It had to be

```
triSup :: Num a => Mat a -> Bool
```

So I made this chunk of code, right here:

```
type Mat a = [[a]]

triSup :: Num a => Mat a -> Bool  
triSup m = all (==0) (zero m)

zero :: Num a => Mat a -> [a]  
zero m = concat (zipWith ($) (zipWith ($) (replicate (length m) take) [0..((length m)-1)]) m)
```

Problem is, ghci says he can't compare my Numeric a's with 0 (which I do not understand why btw). It says I need Eq a, even though I cannot alter the function's type. I need help.

Comment: Is it possible that you're expected to use hugs instead of GHC? GHC differs from Haskell 98 (and maybe Haskell 2010?) in that it doesn't make `Eq` a superclass of `Num`, so it is slightly non-standard in this and a couple other ways.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no, I am certainly expected to use GHC...

Comment: Then you will either need to use a very old GHC or chat with your teacher. What you ask can't be done in modern Haskell.

Comment: Is there a different method of checking for this property which doesn't involve `Eq`? (I thought of adding up the first 0,1,...,_n_ values and seeing if the sum is 0, but that obviously fails if you have any negative numbers...)

Comment: How would you "see" if the sum is 0 without using `==`, which is defined in `Eq`?

Comment: There is no nontrivial function of type `Num a => a -> Bool`.

Comment: It may help to keep in mind that the type `a` in `Num a` can be a function type such as `e -> Integer`. You can't directly compare functions.

Comment: I am not aware of any other methods that may not need to go through this problem. But I certainly cannot say that they do not exist. Nonetheless, we has to do this exercise with higher order functions, so this was automatically what I chose to do.

Comment: I don't see how this exercise involves higher-order functions.

Comment: zipWith and all are the Higher order functions that allow me not to have to write the function with explicit recursion

Comment: Ah - I was wondering why you didn't use explicit recursion, which would have been simpler. By the way, you can also use `f <*> x`, which does the same thing as `zipWith ($) f x`.

Comment: Omg, that help a hell of a lot ! Thank you !

Comment: I just e-mailed my teacher and yes, it really was a mistake in the making of the exercise